# SELECT LEFT JOIN with USING and WHERE AND OR

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm struggling with the following sql query to display a search result from a mysql db

This works

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    lagerbestand
LEFT JOIN
    verkaufspreis USING (materialnummer)
WHERE
    lagerbestand.level='2' AND (lagerbestand.materialnummer='$suche' OR lagerbestand.materialkurztext LIKE '%$suche%')
```

This works too

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    lagerbestand
LEFT JOIN
    verkaufspreis USING (materialnummer)
WHERE
    lagerbestand.materialnummer='$suche' OR verkaufspreis.bezeichnung_fr LIKE '%$suche%'
```

But this doesn't work

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    lagerbestand
LEFT JOIN
    verkaufspreis USING (materialnummer)
WHERE
    lagerbestand.level='2' AND (lagerbestand.materialnummer='$suche' OR verkaufspreis.bezeichnung_fr LIKE '%$suche%')
```

The only difference is the last bit.

lagerbestand.materialkurztext is changed to verkaufspreis.bezeichnung_fr

Then the script just loads for ever.

Comment: Probably worth looking at `FULLTEXT` indexes and `MATCH ... AGAINST` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Also try *explaining* the query - run it directly on MySQL (e.g. through Workbench or PMA) but prefix it with `EXPLAIN` - that might give you a better handle on what's going squiffy.

Comment: After all the brilliant help provided in the answers below, and comments above, if you're still struggling,  see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I try to come up with an example

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using indexes to speed the query.  Also, drop the quotes from `2` if it is not necessary:

```
SELECT *
FROM lagerbestand l LEFT JOIN
     verkaufspreis v
     USING (materialnummer)
WHERE l.level = 2 AND (l.materialnummer = '$suche' OR v.materialnummer LIKE '%$suche%');
```

For this query, you want an index on `lagerbestand(level, bezeichnung_fr)` and `verkaufspreis(materialnummer, bezeichnung_fr)`.

I'm not guaranteeing this will result in great performance, but it is a place to start.

EDIT:

`OR` can be hard to optimize for a query.  The next idea is to use `union all`:

```
SELECT *
FROM lagerbestand l LEFT JOIN
     verkaufspreis v
     USING (materialnummer)
WHERE l.level = 2 AND l.materialnummer = '$suche'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM lagerbestand l JOIN
     verkaufspreis v
     USING (materialnummer)
WHERE l.level = 2 AND (l.materialnummer <> '$suche' AND v.materialnummer LIKE '%$suche%');
```

This might be faster, because the subqueries might be optimized more efficiently.  You can try each one independently to see if there still a performance problem.

Comment: I just find `LEFT JOIN v ... WHERE... OR v.... =...` too complicated a construct to comprehend.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I didn't invent it, but it is not that hard to follow.  As a simplification (ignoring `level`), the OP wants all "suche"s in the first table and then all partial matches to "suche" in the second.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me the same error as my third script in the op. The page just loads for ever

Comment: The problem query (according to OP in the question) has a LIKE predicate on **`bezeichnung_fr`** column. The queries in this answer don't include that predicate.  With that aside... yes, running two *separate* SELECT and combining the results with UNION ALL set operator is the best bet for getting reasonable execution plan. The two SELECT can be optimized independently, using `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan, adding suitable indexes, etc. +10.

Comment: @spencer7593 yes I know, so I changed v.materialnummer to v.bezeichnung_fr to get the desired result. But this is where I get the error. I think it has to do with the fact that I try to compare values from two tables

Comment: @theFinges: What is "the error" you get? (The exact text of the error  message.) It's valid to include conditions on columns from two or more tables. (What is the exact text of the SQL statement that is being sent to MySQL Server? We're going to assume that the string containing the SQL statement isn't being passed through an HTML encoder so the less than sign character "`<`" is being replaced by "`&lt;`", but how do we know our assumption valid?)

Comment: @spencer7593 there is no error text, the page just loads forever and never stops loading. 
Only if I include the code with the UNION ALL I get the error text "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in ..." But I think this has to do with the following php code which displays the results `$results = $conn->query($sql); while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: That "Fatal error:" is because $results is FALSE. And $results is FALSE because the query execution failed. Do a test on $results, and if it's FALSE retrieve the error message e.g. `if (!$results) { printf("Error: %s\n", $conn->error); }`   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to return set specified in the last query, I think the best bet for optimal performance is going to be to break that up into two distinct sets, and combine those with a UNION ALL set operator.

(If `$such` is meant to be variable that is substituted into the SQL text, I would make sure that it has been properly escaped, before it is included.)

```
 SELECT l.*, v.*
   FROM lagerbestand l
   LEFT JOIN verkaufspreis v USING (materialnummer)
  WHERE l.level = '2'
    AND l.materialnummer = '$suche'

  UNION ALL

 SELECT l.*, v.*
   FROM lagerbestand l
   JOIN verkaufspreis v USING (materialnummer)
  WHERE l.level = '2'
    AND NOT ( l.materialnummer <=> '$suche' )
    AND v.bezeichnung_fr LIKE CONCAT('%','$suche','%')
```

---

Then I would tune each of those SELECT separately, using `EXPLAIN`, making sure appropriate indexes are available.

```
 ON verkaufspreis (materialnummer, bezeichnung_fr, ... )

 ON lagerbestand (level, materialnummer, ... )
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but now I get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in ..."

Comment: I think it has to do with the part after the select query

`$results = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: @theFinges: the most likely explanation for the error is that the query execution failed. The code should check `$results` after query(), and it it's FALSE, get the error message. I'm not seeing an error in the SQL in this answer. If it was me, I would test the two SELECT statements separately. In terms of performance, I expect the second SELECT will be the tall post.  I'm not spotting any obvious problem with the SQL, aside from the potential of SQL Injection through `$suche`.

Comment: @theFinges:  1) test each of the SELECT *separately* 2) use EXPLAIN to see the execution plan 3) if suitable indexes are not available, add appropriate index